# Security concerning using Windows 7 as a web server

Tags: windows, webserver

Can Windows 7 be used for hosting a low traffic website which only use php and mysql and nothing else, like email, file hosting, etc.

Comment: You say it's about security, but you ask performance questions. Please clarify.

Comment: This question appears to be more about performance.  Migrate to serverfault.com?  Also, look into IIS with PHP.

Comment: Even after the edit.  Still seems off-topic.

Comment: This is off topic here, and is not going to be welcomed on SF, as the answer is a simple 'yes' but would need a whole lot more detail if it were to be a useful question.

Answer (score 4):

The operating system you use is not the issue: it's how you configure it. All the typical web server security configurations apply to .... web servers. Linux, Windows, Raspberry Pi, the same concepts apply.

You also have to consider the impact of the network, and if you are hoping to use the Windows 7 box for other things, like personal computing. Any service you expose to the Internet has to be considered to be 'already compromised' and you need to set yourself up with that idea already in mind. Your secure design starts from there.